# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter '**EmployeeId**' of non-nullable type **'System.Int32'** for method **'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult getsingledata(Int32)'** in **'sample.Controllers.CtoVController'**.

An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

How to overcome this error

Comment: you action requires a parameter which is passed null

Comment: Start by showing us some of the relevant code.